# A is an arrays: determine if there are two integers that are present in A the same number of times

Tags: arrays, algorithm, pseudocode, find-occurrences

For example: A=[1,2,2,3,4,4,5]->true; A=[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]->false.

```
proc(A){
list = newList()
for (i=1 to length[A]) {
   occ = 0
   n = a[i]
   for (j = 1 to length[A]) {
       if(a[j] == n)
            occ++
    } 
    list.append(occ)
}
```

but dosen't work because in the list will be repeated elements.I thought about using an algorithm similar to countingSort but I don't know the length of the support vector.

Any help? In pseudocode will be fine.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us YOUR code!

Comment: Put your code in the question and format it with the `{}` button to make a code block

Comment: @Avery Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @ThomasShelby and u just want to return true or false right if u find that there are two integers in the array that occur same number of times, right ? And which language are u trying to do this in, because by making use on in built data structures ur task will become much easier

Comment: @zenwraight i should use Pseudocode and data structures like arrays, list, tree...

Comment: Can u explain me how is this false - A=[1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]->false. Count of 3 and 4 both are equal right

Comment: @zenwraight damn misprint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the use of data structures like map and set, this task could be accomplished very easily.

```
Algorithm:-
-> Loop through the array and store it in hashmap with key as the value of the array element and value as the count of it's occurrence.
-> Create an empty set
-> Loop through the map and keep storing the value of every key in the set and if somewhere in between looping u come across any value that's already there in the set, then return true else if u reach the end of map, then return false.
```

Let's look as Pseudocode now.

```
Pseudocode:-
-> we have input array as arr and length n
-> we create an empty map - m[int, int]
-> for (i -> 0 to n-1)
   {
      m[arr[i]]++;
   }
-> This in the end will give us our map which we want with key as the array element and value as it's count
-> create a set - s
-> iterate over map m as key -> value
   {
      if (value present in s) {
         return true
      }
      s.insert(value)
    }
-> If we reach here then it means we never came across any pair of elements whose occurrence is same, so return false.
```

Hope this helps!